# YouTube Data API returning access not configured error

Tags: android, youtube-api, sha1, android-youtube-api, google-developers-console

We recently enabled YouTube data API for reading users YouTube channel id. Everything worked normally in the test project which we created.

Now we requested access to YouTube scope on our production project and got it approved from google.

But when we are trying to use that project, we are getting this error.

```
{
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project 123 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=123 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=123" }   ],   "code": 403,   "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project 123 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=123 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."  
}
```

All stack overflow answers suggest to create a new project and use that. But we cannot disable our existing project as it is in production and is being used for google login.

We tried creating a new project and use existing SHA1 but google does not allow same SHA1 to be used across multiple projects. Is there any workaround for this situation?

Comment: If you got approved then enable it from API Library -> https://console.developers.google.com/

Comment: i already have it enabled @RanjeetLuhar

Comment: I posted a valid answer. Only one I've seen at StackOverflow that explain how to fix the problem. It was closed as to be a comment by @bhargav-rao